# How to enforce method execution from abstract class?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Provided that we have following classes:

```
public class B extends A{
    @PostConstruct
    public void setUp(){
        a = new XYZ();
        addListener();
    }    
}

public abstract class A{
    X a;

    public void addListener(){
        a.addChangeListener();
    }
}
```

In any implementation of class A there should be provided an initialization of 'a' property. Let's assume that each X implementations must override addChangeListener and that registering the listener is fundamental and necessary for each implementation of A. Is there a way to free developers of subsequent implementations of class A from remembering about this 'addListener' call each time and just put it somehow in A and forget about it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried to make an initialization block in `A`?

Comment: Yeah, that won't work, just tried

Comment: Have you tried putting an `@PostConstruct` method on A?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't provide `a` as a constructor argument and then put the call to `addListener` in the constructor of `A`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @chrylis, use the `@PostConstruct` on A rather than each subclass of A. (Note the [spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html%20spec) says only 1 method may be annotated in this manner.

Something like:

```
public interface X {
    void addChangeListener();
}

public abstract class A {
    X a;

    protected abstract X newX();

    protected void setUp() {}

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        a = newX();
        a.addChangeListener();
        setUp();
    }
}
```

This allows forces the construction of the subclass, frees the implementors from remembering the addListener() call, while still allows them to perform class-specific initialization.

Comment: This isn't a bad plan if you know that you'll always be running with dependency injection.  If you're *not* though, this won't work at all.

Comment: After some time I got to the same conclusion but you were first writing it here. That's what I was looking for.

Comment: @IanMcLaird Can you give an example for the case where it won't?

Comment: If you are not in a container that recognizes the @PostConstruct annotation it will not work. If you are a JEE application or running within Spring it will. The container must recognize the standard annotations and be instructed to scan the class in question.

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd take a different approach.  Use the constructor to force the dependency to be met.  Unless there's some reason why you *have* to use `@PostConstruct`, I think this will meet your needs.

```
public class B extends A{
    public B() {
        super(new XYZ());
    }
}

public abstract class A{
    X a;

    public A(X a){
        this.a = a;
        a.addChangeListener();
    }
}
```

Programmers extending `A` will be forced to pass in the initialization of `a` as a constructor parameter, so they can't forget -- the class will fail to compile if they don't do it.  The constructor will always call the `a.addChangeListener()` method, and you know they can't skip out or override you because it's the constructor, and you don't need any annotations.

Comment: I still have to remember to call super() so for me it's not a good solution.

Comment: No you don't.  If an abstract class has a constructor with parameters, you'll get a compiler error if you don't invoke it.

Comment: Ok, you're right. I don't have to remember it - I just have to put it in every inherited class which is better however solution provided by @wbdarby does not require repeating same/similar method's call.

Comment: But it does require you to implement a specific method in every subclass, *and* use a container that manages dependency injection for you.